# How to commit a candidate item in sample soft keyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

In the function `pickSuggestionManually(int index)`
the commented documentation says the following:

```
// If we were generating candidate suggestions for the current
// text, we would commit one of them here.  But for this sample,
// we will just commit the current text.
commitTyped(getCurrentInputConnection());
```

Now, how to commit one of the candidate suggestions?

Can anyone help please?

Regards,
Sayantan

Answer (score 6):

Add a function like:

```
public String getSuggestion(int index)
{
    return index >= 0 && mSuggestions != null && index < mSuggestions.size() ? mSuggestions.get(index) : "";
}
```

to CandidateView.java, then replace the code you referenced with something like:

```
        if (mCandidateView != null) {
            getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(
                    mCandidateView.getSuggestion(index),
                    mCandidateView.getSuggestion(index).length());
            mComposing.setLength(0);
            updateCandidates();
        }
```